# Make selected item Highlighted with Angular and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, highlight

Now I have a list of Items. Items are retried from API.
Now I need to highlight Selected Item. when the page loads the first item is selected and then I select another item so highlight this item and the first item's highlight removed.

In this Img I selected the second item and add a border as shows it selected by the user.

[image: Ex Img]

```
<!--I share Code-->
   <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-item >
          {{item.name}}
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ngClass` for this.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selectItem(item)">
    <ion-item [ngClass]="{'item-selected':item.value === yourSelectedModelValue}">
        {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

And inside your class.

```
selectItem (item) {
    this.yourSelectedModelValue = item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! item.value = name & what about yourSelectedModelValue.

Comment: @Pritesh `yourSelectedModelValue` thats the value for which the selection to be done

Comment: I have sub item so how can i highlight that

Comment: @Pritesh same logic. Use `ngClass` with another scope variable.